# Vuetify CRUD table items binding to edit dialog values despite setting to different copies of the object data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a simple CRUD table for manipulating values. I have created a duplicate of the problem that I am facing using dummy data. I have built out three different components as far: the FoodTable component, the EditDialog Component, and the Delete Component. I am having issues with the EditDialog component. When I update values in the edit component, the corresponding values also update in the DataTable, despite having passed a copy of the values to the EditDialog component.

This is what the code looks like:

FoodTable.vue

```
<template>
    <div>

        <EditDialog :IsOpen="editIsOpen" :EditObject="editObject" @edit-closed="editClosed" />

        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
            <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                <v-icon @click="openEdit(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import EditDialog from '../components/EditDialog.vue';
export default {
    name: 'FoodTable',
    components: {
        EditDialog,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                    align: 'start',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'name',
                },
                { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
                { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
                { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
                { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
            ],
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    calories: 159,
                    fat: 6.0,
                    carbs: 24,
                    protein: 4.0,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                    calories: 237,
                    fat: 9.0,
                    carbs: 37,
                    protein: 4.3,
                },
            ],

            //edit
            editIsOpen: false,
            editObject: {},

            //delete
        }
    },
    methods: {
        openEdit(item) {
            this.editIsOpen = true;
            this.editObject = item;
        },
        editClosed() {
            this.editIsOpen = false;
            this.editObject = {};
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

EditDialog.vue

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="isOpen" persistent>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>Edit</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field v-model="editObject.calories"></v-text-field>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn @click="cancelEdit">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn @click="confirmEdit">Confirm</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    name: 'EditDialog',
    props: {
        IsOpen: Boolean,
        EditObject: Object,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isOpen: this.IsOpen,
            editObject: this.EditObject,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        cancelEdit() {
            this.$emit('edit-closed');
        },
        confirmEdit() {
            this.$emit('edit-closed');
        }
    },
    watch: {
        IsOpen() {
            this.isOpen = this.IsOpen;
        },
        EditObject(newEditObject){
            this.editObject = newEditObject;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

When I press the edit icon I am expecting the following to happen:

1. @click event calls openEdit and passes current item.
2. editIsOpen is set to true and editObject is set to item passed to openEdit.
3. These Items are passed as props to the EditDialog component.
4. The EditDialog component watches these props, and when changes, sets local variables isOpen and editObject to the values that the Props hold.
5. The EditDialog component has a text field that binds to the local editObject properties, and allows the user to edit the local object.
6. After pressing submit, the component emits the new object up and sets it in the data table (not yet implemented).

The issue I am having arises around step 5. Instead of only manipulating the local editObject object, the edit dialog is allowing editing both the local variable and the variable attached to the datatable.

EDIT: I overlooked that I was passing by reference. Setting the local data within the watch like this fixed the issue:

```
IsOpen() {
            this.isOpen = this.IsOpen;
            let editObject = {
                name: this.EditObject.name,
                calories: this.EditObject.calories,
                fat: this.EditObject.fat,
                carbs: this.EditObject.carbs,
                protein: this.EditObject.protein,
            }
            this.editObject = editObject;
        }
```

Comment: I guess the issue you are facing is because you are passing the item object from the FoodTable component to the EditDialog component by reference

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...completely crossed my mind that Objects are passed by reference. Creating a local object and setting its properties off the Props properties did the trick. Cheers!

Comment: note: use something like cloneDeep if you have nested arrays or objects.